# Is there a way to test that a std::ranges::views iterator is the end iterator just with the iterator?

Tags: c++, std-ranges

In the following function

```
namespace r = std::ranges;
namespace rv = std::ranges::views;

std::optional<int> find_first_adjacent_duplicate(std::span<int> vals) {
    auto pairs = vals | rv::slide(2);
    auto adj_dup = r::find_if(pairs, [](auto&& r) {return r[0] == r[1]; });
    if (adj_dup != pairs.end()) {
        return (*adj_dup)[0];
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}
```

The only reason I store `vals | rv::slide(2)` in a local variable is because I need a name for the range view so that I can test the result of `find_if` against its end iterator.

I was wondering if there is way to tell if `adj_dup` is `pairs.end()` just given `adj_dup`?

Comment: No, this is not possible. You need another iterator to compare to.

Comment: Are you trying to implement [std::ranges::adjacent_find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/adjacent_find) or is it just an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. But you can express the `find_if` as a `filter` instead:

```
auto adj_dup = vals 
             | rv::slide(2)
             | rv::filter([](auto&& r) {return r[0] == r[1]; });
if (adj_dup) {
    return adj_dup.front()[0];
} else {
    return {};
}
```